# Maintenance on machines that have a SQL Server cluster, both nodes need to be down

Tags: sql-server, clustering

There is going to be an update on the virtualization farm from VMWare 6.7 to VMWare 7. I have a SQL Server cluster in that farm, both machines need to be down to perform the upgrade.

What is the best approach for the SQL Server cluster:

- Shut down the SQL Server service from Configuration Manager?
- Stop the role in the failover cluster manager?
- Shut down the windows cluster?

Any other options to avoid possible problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is going to be an update on the virtualization farm from VMWare 6.7 to VMWare 7. I have a SQL Server cluster in that farm [...]

I sincerely hope the FCI was properly set up and the VMWare team didn't mess up the [shared storage](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/79616). VMWare 7 enforces SCSI-3 PR, finally, and there have been more than a few issues after upgrades.

> Stop the role in the failover cluster manager?

This is what you'd want to do if you're specifically taking it down for a while (as you are). You can also shutdown both operating systems in an orderly fashion and it'll handle things.

I'd prefer to take the role offline first, personally, as then it's down and doesn't move around depending on the orderly or non-orderly shutdown of the OS instances.